# iOS Delegate Method Never Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I'm having an issue where my delegate method is never called. The `goBack` function is called, but then the `closeShopDetailView` isn't.

I'm trying to have a button press in `HBShopDetailView` to tell `HBShopsVC` to fade out the `HBShopDetailView` subview. I've used a similar delegate pattern before and had no issues, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. I've looked at the other questions on this topic and none of their solutions worked for me either.

I appreciate any and all help!

**HBShopDetailView.h**

```
@protocol HBShopDetailDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)closeShopDetailView;
@end


@interface HBShopDetailView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HBShopDetailDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;

- (id)initWithShopInformation:(PFObject *)shopInfo;

@end
```

**HBShopDetailView.m - Relevant Methods**

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    id<HBShopDetailDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    [strongDelegate closeShopDetailView];
}
```

**HBShopsVC.h**

```
@interface HBShopsVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, HBShopDetailDelegate>

@end
```

**HBShopsVC.m - Relevant Methods**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"touch on row %d", (unsigned)indexPath.row);

    self.shopDetailView = [[HBShopDetailView alloc] initWithShopInformation: self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]];
    self.shopDetailView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.shopDetailView];

    //Fade in the detailView
    self.shopDetailView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.shopDetailView.alpha = 1;
    }];
}

- (void)closeShopDetailView
{
    NSLog(@"closedetailview");
    self.shopDetailView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.shopDetailView.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Inside the `goBack:` method, is `self.delegate` non-nil?

Comment: Is it possible that you delegate property is nil when you attempt to call the method? Try putting a breakpoint in the goBack method and see...

Comment: Obvious question, but is `self.delegate` `nil`?

Comment: add `assert(strongDelegate)`

Comment: I believe that self.delegate might be nil. the (id) is 0x0. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @Daij-Djan where would I add that line?

Comment: just below `id<HBShopDetailDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
`

Comment: @Daij-Djan, I tried that. Then it crashed with this error: Assertion failed: (strongDelegate), function -[HBShopDetailView goBack:]

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes. How can I fix that? I'm not sure why it would be nil.

Comment: Is HopsVC deallocated in the meantime?

Comment: @Daij-Djan no, its not deallocated at all

Comment: override setDelegate and put a breakpoint there.. maybe somebody else is calling it :)

Comment: Hi @Seslyn - still need some help?

Comment: @latenitecoder, I figured it out with some help from a friend. Turned out it was a nib bug in IB. Just out of curiosity though, what were you referencing when you said I could clean up my code?

Comment: I thought your code was assembled incorrectly but apparently not. Glad you got it fixed.